# Anypoint Studio console execution does not go past deployed

Tags: mulesoft

Below is the configuration xml of my small program in Anypoint Studio. What i am trying to do is copying one text file data(pipe delimited) to another text file. The execution goes well but stops at status as "Deployed". I have tried other transformations as well but the result is same. Help is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd">

    <flow name="texttoexcelFlow" doc:id="42aaa83a-e26a-4f6d-8d2f-da3613a8d232" initialState="started">
        <file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="89fa46c9-aa14-4a79-b7ab-e609b9fad501" path="D:\Mulesoft Input\Name.txt" outputMimeType="application/json" outputEncoding="UTF-8">
            <repeatable-in-memory-stream />
        </file:read>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="86dc86b8-99ed-4bee-b5bc-e07616e44431" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/csv headerLineNumber = 0 , header = false , separator = "|"
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    FirstName: payload01.FirstName ,
    LastName: payload01.LastName
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <file:write doc:name="Write" doc:id="3884725e-3870-4ef1-9e05-b10a2274dfa6" path="C:\Users\aseem\Desktop\Mulesoft Output\Excel.txt">
        </file:write>
    </flow>
</mule>
"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something to trigger the flow to run. `file:read` doesn’t do this automatically.

All flows need a ‘Source’ to trigger them unless you are calling them from other flows using `flow-ref` (or from dataweave using a lookup()).

If you know the exact file you want then you can put a scheduler before your `file:read` to trigger the flow:

```
<scheduler>
  <scheduling-strategy>
    <fixed-frequency startDelay="5" frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
  </scheduling-strategy>
</scheduler>
```

Or you can use a file:listener to listen for new files in a directory etc as the source directly:

```
<flow name="onNewFile">
  <file:listener config-ref="file" directory="test-data/in" autoDelete="true">
    <scheduling-strategy>
      <fixed-frequency frequency="1000"/>
    </scheduling-strategy>
  </file:listener>
  ...
</flow>
```

You can use fixed frequency or cron. More details here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/scheduler-xml-reference